# jQuery + RGBA color animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

Does anyone know if jQuery can handle an animation like:

```
rgba(0,0,0,0.2) → rgba(0,255,0,0.4)
```

I know there is a [plugin](http://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/blob/master/jquery.color.js) to handle color animations, but this might be too modern?

Comment: Useful answers over at this question marked duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194745/changing-rgba-alpha-transparency-with-jquery

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Uh, nevermind. Found an amazing modification to the jquery color plugin.

http://pioupioum.fr/sandbox/jquery-color/

Comment: Um, just to add another random coolness tidbit for those interested. RGBA cross browser via php image generation: http://leaverou.me/2009/02/bulletproof-cross-browser-rgba-backgrounds/

Comment: Unfortunately this modded version doesn't seem to support modern browsers :(

Answer (score 26):

## **Using CSS3 animation** (no javascript)

You can also achieve the same effect using CSS3 animation. See below,

**Step 1:** Create a keyframe for your animation

```
@keyframes color_up {
    from {
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
    to {
        background-color: rgba(0,255,0,0.4);
    }
}
```

**Step 2:** Use the animation rules.

```
  animation-name: color_up;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/2Dbrj/3/

## **Using jQuery**

jQuery now supports **[color](http://jqueryui.com/animate/) animation** with **RGBA** support as well. This actually animates from one color to other.

```
$(selector).animate({
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,255,0,0.4)'
});
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/2Dbrj/2/

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt Updated answer with CSS3

Comment: The CSS3 JSFiddle doesn't seem to want to work in Chrome. Thanks, though!

Comment: @Monk You need to add -webkit- for keyframes see http://jsfiddle.net/rparree/2QsL6/1/

Comment: Better solution!!

Answer (score 2):

use [jquery UI](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js) for handle that, `$(object).animate({color : 'rgba(0,0,0,.2)'},500)`