# changing rgba alpha transparency with jquery

Tags: jquery, animation, css, opacity, rgba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery + RGBA color animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242368/jquery-rgba-color-animations)

hey,

i want to change the opacity of an rgba value on hover, but the opacity stays at .07.. maybe ou can help me find the mistake.

CSS (IE hacks are in seperate file - no need to mention them here)

```
.boxcaption{
   float: left;
   position: absolute;
   height: 100px;
   width: 100%;
   background: rgb(255, 144, 11);
   background: rgba(255, 144, 11, 0.7);
}
```

JS

```
var thumbslide = $('.boxgrid.captionfull').click(function() {
    $('.boxgrid.captionfull.clicked').removeClass('clicked').children('.cover').stop().animate({top: 230, background: 'rgba(255, 144, 11, 0.7)'}, 350);
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked').children('.cover').stop().animate({top: 0, height:"230px", background: 'rgba(255, 144, 11, 1)'}, 350);
});
```

Answer (score -5, accepted):

the jquery color plugin doesn't support rgba. use this instead: [link text](http://roxority.com/sharepoint-zen/jquery-color-animations-adding-rgba-alpha-channel-support.html)

Comment: thanks for the link. there was a usefull link in the comments: http://pioupioum.fr/sandbox/jquery-color/

Comment: This link requires a login.

Comment: The linked resource is broken.

Comment: Due the fact that the link needs a login, this answer is useless. -1

Comment: Sorry. It didn't need it before.

Answer (score 1):

I get the feeling (***untested*** guess) that jQuery is not checking the CSS background property for `rbga(...)` and thus not applying a hack fix to change the `filter:alpha()`.

I think you'll need to change `opacity:1` separately.

```
.animate({top:0,height:"230px",background:'rgb(255, 144, 11)',opacity:1}, 350);
```

Comment: sadly this doesn't work.. but maybe i can go by removing the rgba value since i have a rgb value for fallback?

Comment: does adding `zoom:1` or `display:inline-block` to the css help? I'm wondering if there is an issue due to the element not having "hasLayout" in IE?

Comment: i'm testing on FF3.6. IE gets triggered via conditional comments and has a zoom:1 aswell as Filters for the opacity hack since i need type with full opacity over the transparent div.