# jQuery Animate() and BackgroundColor

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to create a simple pulse effect by changing the background color using JQuery. However, I can't get the backgroundColor to animate.

```
function show_user(dnid) {
    /* dnid is HTML ID of a div. */
    if (! $(dnid).is(':visible')) {
        $(dnid).show()
    }
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(dnid).offset().top});
    $(dnid).animate({backgroundColor: "#db1a35"}, 1200);
}
```

What's strange is that this alternate animation works:

```
$(dnid).animate({opacity: "toggle"}, 1200);
```

But it's not what I want at all.

Additionally the show() and scroll functionality in the function work fine. It's just the background color animation that doesn't.

The function above is called by this link
    `<a href="#" onclick="javascript:show_user('#9e4cde88b90004ea722e9e129ed83747')">Locate Me</a>`

Could someone help me animate the background color?

=========

Thanks everyone for the help. Lots of similar answers. Here's what I ended up with

In my header

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.1.2.min.js"></script>`

Then in my show_user function right after the scroll animation.

```
var bgcol = $(dnid).css('backgroundColor');
$(dnid).animate({backgroundColor: "#db1a35"}, 2000);
$(dnid).animate({backgroundColor: bgcol}, 2000);
```

That gives a relatively quick red "pulse" that will draw the user's eyes.

Again, thanks for the help.

Comment: You'll need to use either jQuery UI, or a color plugin to animate colours.

Comment: Not sure if this is still the case, but Jon Resig himself made a background plugin for solely animating background colors, it's not something built into jQuery.

Comment: May be this should help http://stackoverflow.com/a/14362680/297641

Comment: @DavidThomas I think jQuery has included color animation sometime back.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14362680/297641

Comment: @Vega: I stand corrected! In which version of jQuery did that change occur? (I ask, though I'll go look at the API in a moment anyway...). No, wait: the API still states: "width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color() plugin is used."

Comment: Works for me in jQuery 1.9 http://jsfiddle.net/aaqHt/

Comment: @DavidThomas Looks like it was added in jQuery 1.9 release http://jqueryui.com/changelog/1.9.0/ under Effects.

Comment: @Vega, despite the API (or my misunderstanding of it), your demo definitely proves it to work. Weird. Perhaps now is the time for espresso...

Comment: open your console and type `$('#footer').animate({'background-color':'#000000'}, 1200)` and watch the footer go black on this page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery animate backgroundColor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

jQuery cannot animate colours by default. In order to animate colours, use the official [jQuery.Color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) plugin.

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color() plugin is used).

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks for the explanation why backgroundColor is excluded from the standard library. I've created a solution based on your recommendation.

Comment: why not just animate the css property: `$(dnid).animate({'background-color': "#db1a35"}, 1200);` see my answer below

Answer (score 4):

jQuery supports animation between any **numeric** CSS properties, which does not include colors. However, there are other libraries that make animating colors possible. One such library is the aptly-named [jQuery Color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/). Its [readme page](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/blob/master/README.md) shows several examples of how to use it to animate between colors using the jQuery `.animate()` function

Comment: Awesome. I didn't realize that jQuery limited animations to numeric properties. Thanks for the thorough explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Use the CSS `animation` property and `keyframes`

[**See it in action**](http://jsfiddle.net/sbLgQ/)

**HTML**

```
<div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    background-color: red;
    height: 200px; width: 200px;
    -webkit-animation: pulse 1s ease-in 0 infinite normal both;
    -moz-animation: pulse 1s ease-in 0 infinite normal both;
    -o-animation: pulse 1s ease-in 0 infinite normal both;
    animation: pulse 1s ease-in 0 infinite normal both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
    0% { background-color: red; }
    65% { background-color: #7F0093; }
    100% { background-color: blue; }
}
@-moz-keyframes pulse {
    0% { background-color: red; }
    65% { background-color: #7F0093; }
    100% { background-color: blue; }
}
@-ms-keyframes pulse {
    0% { background-color: red; }
    65% { background-color: #7F0093; }
    100% { background-color: blue; }
}
@-o-keyframes pulse {
    0% { background-color: red; }
    65% { background-color: #7F0093; }
    100% { background-color: blue; }
}
@keyframes pulse {
    0% { background-color: red; }
    65% { background-color: #7F0093; }
    100% { background-color: blue; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this simple option for creating this effect!

Comment: You're welcome `:)` Don't forget to check cross browser compatibility if you're planning to use it in production

Comment: Broken on Firefox 27.0.1

Answer (score 0):

you must first set the background to the from color or it wont do anything 2nd time around.
You also typoed the css property `'background-color'` and put it in quotes like i didn't :)

```
$(dnid).css({'background-color': "#ffffff"});

$(dnid).animate({'background-color': "#db1a35"}, 1200);
```

Comment: If there are other style properties on the thing you don't want to reset, you can just do `$(dnid).css('background-color', '#ffffff');`

Comment: Does this work? Can you jsFiddle this? I couldn't get this to work for me.

Comment: Sorry @Chud37 it turns out I was making use of the jQueryUI library for the color animation. http://jsfiddle.net/aw42aj2L/

Answer (score 0):

Just add this below your jQuery script and you are done:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.color-animation/1/mainfile"></script>
```