# Fade in body colour depending on class

Tags: jquery, css, slider, fullpage.js

Trying to animate a background in a slider similar to this website - http://www.legworkstudio.com/

I'm using a plugin called fullpage.js which adds a class "fp-viewing-#" to the body depending on which slide is selected (starting at 0).

I can't seem to figure out why the lines below don't work. I've tried both .animate + .css to do this.

```
if ($("body").hasClass("fp-viewing-1")) {
    $("body").animate({"background" : "red"}, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Animate() and BackgroundColor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16863640/jquery-animate-and-backgroundcolor). Also see [jQuery animate backgroundColor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor)

Comment: `background` is not an animatable property: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_animate.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use transition on your body element

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].onclick = function() {
  document.body.className = 'red';
};
```

```css
body {
  background-color: green;
  transition: background-color 2s;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 2s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 2s;
}

body.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button>Change color</button>
    </body>
</html>
```