# CSS to blur the background color into a light, opaque blue

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I have a div which sits in another div which I am trying to color the background of and have it be about 50% of the solid color `#0F7BD5`, and then blur into a more transparent version of that color.  I have come up with this CSS but it's showing a sharp edge instead of the blur / fading effect that I'm trying to create.  This is the CSS that I've come up with:

```
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
top: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
-webkit-background-background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-180deg, #0F7BD5 0, rgba(15,123,213,0.7) 40%, rgba(15,123,213,0.6) 45%, rgba(15,123,213,0.52) 50%, rgba(15,123,213,0.4) 55%, rgba(15,123,213,0.3) 59%, rgba(15,123,213,0.2) 63%, rgba(15,123,213,0.15) 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(270deg, #0F7BD5 0, rgba(15,123,213,0.7) 40%, rgba(15,123,213,0.6) 45%, rgba(15,123,213,0.52) 50%, rgba(15,123,213,0.4) 55%, rgba(15,123,213,0.3) 59%, rgba(15,123,213,0.2) 63%, rgba(15,123,213,0.15) 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(270deg, #0F7BD5 0, rgba(15,123,213,0.7) 40%, rgba(15,123,213,0.6) 45%, rgba(15,123,213,0.52) 50%, rgba(15,123,213,0.4) 55%, rgba(15,123,213,0.3) 59%, rgba(15,123,213,0.2) 63%, rgba(15,123,213,0.15) 100%);
```

The colors in-between don't matter, as long as it starts with this `#0F7BD5` with no transparency, and ends with this `rgba(15,123,213,0.15)`.

Comment: can you show us all the code that deals with the divs and the css that goes along with it?

Comment: This may be a duplicate: I think there are css and jquery animate solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242368/jquery-rgba-color-animations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to specify extra color-stop positions as long as the colors in between do not matter. Just specify the start and end colors and that should be enough (first `div` in snippet). The browser would automatically split the colors evenly and gradually.

When you add extra color-stop positions in between, the gradient is forced to have the specified color at the specified point and this produces the sharp edge effect (second `div` in snippet). Sharp edges are produced because of uneven distribution of colors. For example, for the first 40% of the gradient, the alpha changes from 1 to 0.7 but for the next 5% (40% to 45%), it suddenly drops by 0.1.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
#gradual:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(270deg, #0F7BD5, rgba(15, 123, 213, 0.15));
}
#sharp:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(270deg, #0F7BD5 0, rgba(15, 123, 213, 0.7) 40%, rgba(15, 123, 213, 0.6) 45%, rgba(15, 123, 213, 0.52) 50%, rgba(15, 123, 213, 0.4) 55%, rgba(15, 123, 213, 0.3) 59%, rgba(15, 123, 213, 0.2) 63%, rgba(15, 123, 213, 0.15) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="gradual"></div>
<div id="sharp"></div>
```