# Animating background colour from solid to transparent isn't working

Tags: jquery, css

Why can't  I animate a background colour to `transparent`? Here is my code:

```
$('#cs4').animate({'backgroundColor':'#ff6600'}, 2000);    

setTimeout(function() {    
    $('#cs4').animate({'backgroundColor':'transparent'}, 2000);
}, 2000);
```

Guys, i have already the plugin. its not the question. my question is how to render the bg transparent. with normal colors it works fine.

thanks in advance

Comment: See jQuery animate to transparent [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679864/jquery-animate-to-transparent][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679864/jquery-animate-to-transparent

Comment: Don't you want to change the opacity... not the background color?

Comment: hexxagonal, if i change opacity it hides also the text. not a big deal ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot animate background colors (or any color change for that matter) without a plugin. jQuery UI does this: http://jqueryui.com/

Here is a demo for animating color change: http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/

You can build a small version of the library with their download tool that only has this functionality.

Comment: The [`jQuery.color`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) plugin can do it, too.  Just in case you don't want the added bulk of UI.

Comment: That's a good call. A small version of jQuery UI is still like 50KB or something. Although you don't need the CSS for this functionality.

Comment: I agree, the CSS implementation is generally very nice, however if you need to support older browsers (which still make up a disgusting portion of browser usage) then CSS won't do.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use an extra jQuery plugin, consider using CSS3 animations.

You will lose some support in old browsers, but animation is no necessary functionality.

Example syntax (with only `-webkit` vendor prefix for simplicity):

```
#cs4 { -webkit-animation: fadeOut 2s ease-in; }

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
    from {background:#ff6600;}
    to {background:transparent;}
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jtpjH/)

[More information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/@keyframes)

Comment: You can also use `-webkit-transition`, are you award if `keyframes` perform faster than `transition`s?

Comment: Transitions are a better way to do it though

Comment: Yeah, you'd generally want to go with `-transition` for a simple animation like this.

Answer (score 2):

Use this jQuery plugin

http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#cs4').animate({'backgroundColor':'#ff6600'}, 2000);    

setTimeout(function() {    
    $('#cs4').animate({'backgroundColor':'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)'}, 2000);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for your answer. It would be nice if you could also add an explanation of what the problem was and why this helps...