# Jquery change border style on all specify divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to change the border color of my div when i click on it with this function but when i click on one of the 3 divs the border color is much brighter.

Every Border fades the color but only the active not. Why?

Here is my Fiddle: [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YngEE/2/)

```
$('.re').click(function() {
    $('.re').removeClass('active').removeAttr('style');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});



$(".test1").click(function() {
    $(".mainNavitem").stop().animate({"border-right-color":"rgba(255,255,255, 0.2)"}, 800);
    $(".active").stop().animate({"backgroundColor":"transparent"}, 800);
    $(".bg").stop().animate({"backgroundColor":"rgb(199, 55, 59)"}, 800);

    });

$(".test2").click(function() {
    $(".mainNavitem").stop().animate({"border-right-color":"rgba(255,255,255, 0.5)"}, 800);
    $(".active").stop().animate({"backgroundColor":"transparent"}, 800);
    $(".bg").stop().animate({"backgroundColor":"rgb(199, 55, 59)"}, 800);
});

$(".test3").click(function() {
    $(".mainNavitem").stop().animate({"border-right-color":"rgba(255,255,255, 1)"}, 800);
    $(".active").stop().animate({"backgroundColor":"transparent"}, 800);
    $(".bg").stop().animate({"backgroundColor":"rgb(199, 55, 59)"}, 800);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use background-color instead of backgroundColor. And animating to transparent doesn't work properly. Check out this post [jQuery animate to transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679864/jquery-animate-to-transparent)

You could animate to white if that solves the problem. Like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/YngEE/5/

```
    $(".active").stop().animate({"background-color":"#fff"}, 800);
```