# hover() backgroundColor problem

Tags: jquery, menu, jquery-animate

```
$('li > a').hover(
  function(){
   $(this).animate({
    backgroundColor: '#2a639a',
    color: '#fff'
   },300).corner('5px');
  },
  function(){
   $(this).animate({
    background: 'transparent',
    color: '#444'
   },300);
  }
 );
```

What's wrong with background: 'transparent'?
turns back white, not transparent

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663568/how-do-i-animate-a-background-color-to-transparent-in-jquery) for a workaround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Important thing to note: Transparent in CSS is different from 0% Opacity.

Opacity can be graduated, whereas tranparent is either on or off. Therefore you cannot animate transparent to or from a solid colour and expect a smooth transition. If you try, most browsers will treat it as either black or white for the purposes for the animation, which I think is what you're seeing here.

Animating the opacity instead may give you a smoother transition, though of course it is different (for starters it affects the whole element, not just the background, plus there are browser compatibility issues to consider).

Answer (score 0):

You can't animate the background property.

Maybe you can use a sprite and use the [BackgroundPosition Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/backgroundPosition-Effect)

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to animate the background-color only with jQuery. jQuery only supports numeric values as stated [in the jQuery-API](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) You can use [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/) to animate the background-color.